# my codes aren't working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to creat a little website that ask user a number from a prompt. then a message will appear on a div tag that tell users what grade they got. it doesn't work.

Exemple: if I got 90%, a message will appear and tell me that my grade is A+.

here are the codes:

```
<h1>Prelab1 Ex2</h1><br>
<div id="div2"></div>
<script>

  var inputperc = prompt("Enter a percentage");


  if(inputperc > 100 || inputperc < 0 || isNaN(inputperc)){
    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "Enter a valid Percentage value  between 0 and 100";
    else{
    if(inputperc >= 90 && inputperc <= 100){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "A+";
        }
        if(inputperc>90 && inputperc<100){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "A+";
      }
      if(inputperc>85 && inputperc<89){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "A";
      }
      if(inputperc>80 && inputperc<84){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "A-";
      }
      if(inputperc>77 && inputperc<79){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "B+";
      }
      if(inputperc>73 && inputperc<76){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "B";
      }
      if(inputperc>70 && inputperc<72){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "B-";
      }
      if(inputperc>67 && inputperc<69){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "C+";
      }
      if(inputperc>63 && inputperc<66){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "C";
      }
      if(inputperc>50 && inputperc<62){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "C-";
      }
      if(inputperc>57 && inputperc<59){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "D+";
      }
      if(inputperc>53 && inputperc<56){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "D";
      }
      if(inputperc>50 v&& inputperc<52){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "D-";
      }
      if(inputperc>0 && inputperc<49){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "f";
      }
      }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a user enters text into an input field it is considered a `string`. So you need to convert it to an `integer`. `parseInt` around your prompt is the easiest way. the `10` is just saying that you're using 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (base10)... not something like 0100100101 (base2).

```
var inputperc = parseInt(prompt("Enter a percentage"), 10);
```

Comment: `parseInt` defaults to base 10 for the majority of inputs. Also, the string value will be implicitly cast to a `Number` type. Not saying these aren't good suggestions, but they're not what's preventing his code from working. His code has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Small error:

```
 ...
  if(inputperc > 100 || inputperc < 0 || isNaN(inputperc)){
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "Enter a valid Percentage value  between 0 and 100";
    } else { // <-- forgot to close the if.
    if(inputperc >= 90 && inputperc <= 100){
 ...
```

Also as already mentioned it's a good idea to convert `inputperc` to an Number with `parseInt()`. Also make sure to remove the extra `}` at the end because of this.

Comment: I put "else" statement inside "If" statement so I close the "If" statement ate the end of codes after the closing bracket for "else". Becaue I thought it possible to put a else statement inside a If.

Comment: Yes but we want to close the `if statement` then add an `else`. Your `if statement` checked if it's invalid, then the only way to run the other `if statements` would be if the number was invalid first, which isn't what you want. You can't place an `else` inside and `if` unless you have another `if` first. Since it goes `if(..){...}else{...}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a syntax error as spencer pointed out. You should consider writing a `getGrade` function though.

```
var getGrade = function (percent) {
    if (percent > 100 || percent < 0 || isNaN(percent)) {
        return "Enter a valid Percentage value  between 0 and 100";
    }
    if (percent >= 90 && percent <= 100)    return "A+";
    if (percent > 90 && percent < 100)      return "A+"; 
    if (percent > 85 && percent < 89)       return "A";
    if (percent > 80 && percent < 84)       return "A-"; 
    if (percent > 77 && percent < 79)       return "B+";
    if (percent > 73 && percent < 76)       return "B";
    if (percent > 70 && percent < 72)       return "B-";
    if (percent > 67 && percent < 69)       return "C+";
    if (percent > 63 && percent < 66)       return "C";
    if (percent > 50 && percent < 62)       return "C-";
    if (percent > 57 && percent < 59)       return "D+";
    if (percent > 53 && percent < 56)       return "D";
    if (percent > 50 && percent < 52)       return "D-";
    if (percent > 0 && percent < 49)        return "F";
    return "Unknown Error"
};

var el      = document.getElementById("div2"),
    percent = prompt("Enter a percentage:"),
    grade   = getGrade(percent);

el.innerHTML = grade;
```